# Flex doesn't work for identifying errors in naming identifiers

Tags: regex, flex-lexer

I'm trying to make a lexical analyzer for a minilanguage. One of the rules refers to the fact that the identifiers are not allowed to start with a digit.
Here are the regular expressions that define a number and an identifier.

```
NUMBER  [+-]?[0-9]+
ID  [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

and the rules defined in the .lxi file:

```
%%
{DELIMITATOR}   printf("Delimitator: %s\n",yytext);
{NUMBER}    printf("Number: %s\n",yytext);
{ID}   printf("Identifier: %s\n",yytext); 
.   printf("Error: %s\n",yytext);
%%
```

The problem appears when in the input file, there are tokens that do not respect the rules for naming identifiers. For instance, for

```
a := 1abc
```

I get the following result:

```
Number: 1;
Identifier: abc;
```

Instead, I would like to receive an error message. Is there something I can do? I also tried to use the trailing context when defining the numbers, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You can't. Flex is correctly identifying tokens that are present, and that is what it is for. You can't write a rule for illegal tokens, and you don't want to.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry: The errors presented in your questions are going to be detected and processed / reported in the syntactic level (bison, yacc or similar).

Nevertheless if you think `1abc` like errors are very common, you can
write a flex specific rule to report it. Example:

```
[0-9][a-zA-Z_]+   fprintf(stderr, "invalid identifier '%s'\n",yytext);
[a-zA-Z]{40,}     fprintf(stderr, "identifier to long '%s'\n",yytext);
```